# Listening for ReactContext value changes in Apps

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I'm attempted to use the ReactContext API where a leaf component (Inner) is attempting to send a message to the root component (App). In the below example, Val and the function used to update Val are exposed using context. The issue here is componentDidUpdate() is not being called on App even when Click me is clicked.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  static contextType = ThemeContext;

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log("update", this.context.val);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MyProvider>
        <Inner />
      </MyProvider>
    );
  }
}

class Inner extends React.Component {
  static contextType = ThemeContext;

  render() {
    return <div onClick={() => this.context.load(1234)}>Click me</div>;
  }
}
```

I've added only relevant code above. Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/o5x1638vry) for this example. I am **expecting** componentDidUpdate do be called in App when Click Me is clicked. Basically, i am looking for a way to listen to context changes in the App component.

Comment: Running your code in that sandbox, I don't see any issues with it? Could you elaborate more on what you are expecting to see?

Comment: updated question. I am expecting componentDidUpdate do be called in App when Click Me is clicked.

Comment: Both `MyProvider` and `Inner` have change but `App` has not, so why would `componentDidUpdate` trigger?